# ERROR: There is no row at position 0 how to fix it

Tags: c#, asp.net

[This image is where after user login, they will be able to see their account details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AFvT.png)

[This image is another small form that allows the user to change the username.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqeGn.png)

Currently, the error is when after changing the username. When it directed back to a page in image 1, it crashes.

```
public void showdata()
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Registration where Username='" + Session["user"] + "'";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds);

    lblUsername.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();// error occur at here. 
    lblEmail.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
    lblName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fullname"].ToString();
    lblContact.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Contactnumber"].ToString();
    lblPassword.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
}
```

I do not understand this error. The error is there is no row at position 0.

Comment: Can you share the error message with full stack trace?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no row at position 0.

Comment: I cant send the screenshot here so sorry

Comment: *"There is no row at position 0"* - the result set is empty. Your query didn't return any rows. Step through your code, look at the final query, and try it in SSMS. Also, you need to learn *now* how to parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that rows exist before attempting to get data from them.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0){
    // Fetch the data... 
}
else
{
    // Handle missing data or show some friendly message 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help if OP is expecting rows.

Comment: what is OP is expecting rows?

Comment: @JingyiTay: ***You*** are "OP" (original poster) in this case. You're expecting that the database has a row where the `Username` matches `Session["user"]`.

Comment: @madreflection agree but it just primary check to validate data exist or not

Comment: If `Session["user"]` is assigned when the user logs in, you shouldn't have to make that check. I'm ignoring edge cases like different session and cookie timeouts. I doubt we're dealing with that at this point.

Comment: sorry i am going to sound stupid but i dont understand what to do.

Comment: Look at my comment above, on the question. You have some debugging to do.

Comment: @Jingyi Tay look debug your code and check what Session["user"] has?

Answer (score 0):

*There is no row at position 0* - that means your result set is empty and you need to check count before access any row.

```
if (ds.Tables == null || ds.Tables.Count == 0 || ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) {
    // Throw the error or retrun the code 
}
```

Note:

- Need to handle null every time before getting value from Session. You can create a custom class for handling all sessions for that. [Refer this link for Custom Class](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/session-helper-class-facade1)
- Before getting value from row also need to handle NULL. like use below method

  ```
  public static T GetValueFromDataRow<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
  {
       if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName) && (object)row[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
       {
          return (T)row[columnName];
       }
       return default;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In the Change() function, there is no code that updates the username in the Session["user"] so what might be happening is that your SELECT command is still using the previous username and thus returning 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In showdata() function is you are sending `Session["user"]` as username value, which you have not set in `Change()` function .

So, in Change() function,to get the updated value first set

```
Session["user"]= txtuserchange.Text
```

Please check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your Session["user"] have valid data and the query return list or object of Registration.